# Trying to send an email using PHP scripting

Tags: php, xampp

I'm running a web server using XAMPP. I have using a web form to send emails using PHP scripting. I was wondering, can some tell me why i'm getting this error?

**Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\format.php on line 24**

Here is my php.ini code, with the relevant part provided:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
```

Here is also my PHP script, just to show you what i coded (I can't see anything wrong with line 24 by the way).

```
<?php

$to = 'lnation@gmail.com';
$subject = 'This is from your company';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$message = <<<EMAIL

Hi! My name is $email

$message

From $name
Oh ya, my email is $email

EMAIL;

$header = '$email';

if($_POST){
mail($to,  $subject, $message, $header);
$feedback = 'Thanks for the email';
}

?>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncomment the sendmail_from setting in the ini file:

sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

(remove the semicolon from the beginning). You might also change the postmaster@localhost to something you'd actually want people to see as a sender

Comment: nicely spotted mate. About changing the "postmaster@localhost", which email account can I use. I heard gmail can give some troubles. Would hotmail be any good?

Comment: Generally this would be a sender from the domain in question (mailman@mydomain.com). Also, as others have noted, when calling the mail() function you should take advantage of the additional headers argument. This will let you set the sender and reply-to addresses in the function itself.

Comment: Another question....should the port number be 25 or 80? When I start and stop Apache in XAMPP it mentions "[Port 80]". Any help?

Comment: SMTP port default should be 25... I don't recommend changing this unless you know what you're doing or your ISP blocks port 25. Port 80 is the default port that Apache serves non encrypted webpages on.

Answer (score 2):

Check the PHP manual on mail:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

You need the FROM headers.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So is this code "additional_headers" the FROM headers. Can you give me an example of how it'll be written out? Thanks.

Comment: Just try in the sample but replace the email addresses.

Comment: Another question saratis. See the "webmaster@example.com", should it be "postmaster@localhost" or would it be the Gmail SMTP, "smtp.gmail.com"? Or can I just simply use my "lnation@gmail.com" gmail address?

Answer (score 2):

Always set from in the script, don't rely on that php setting...

Start using [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), you want regret it...

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a smtp server to send emails from php mail function. try using gmail smtp and script to send mails.

Comment: I used the gmail smtp, but it didn't work. I haven't used the "script to send mails", so i'll try that (and the gmail smtp) after i looked at other solutions. Thank you.